# Android Google Map Finding Nearby Pre-Listed Locations

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an ever increasing list of places identified by lat/long stored in my database. Now at the UI front there is a screen with a place auto-complete textbox means if I type a location there a drop down will appear with places and when I select the place the camera will move there. Also it is required that I display locations nearby (locations as stored in my database). Now the question is how to do this? I can use

```
SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()
```

But the problem is I can't fetch all lat/long from my database and calculate distance without hampering performance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to compute the distances in your database. There are two basic options:

- Implement your own distance method in your database:

  - If your positions are close to each other and close to the test lat/lng you can use Pythagoras's theorem (a ver basic approach that will not be correct in all the cases)
  - To address all the possible cases you can implement yor own [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (the haversine formula *gives great-circle distances between two points on a sphere from their longitudes and latitudes* and is used to compute distances in the `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween()` method).
- Use a GIS database. You can use [SpatiaLite for Android](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android) and use the `ST_Distance` function to filter your positions:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM yourtable
> WHERE ST_DISTANCE(Geometry, MakePoint(yourXcoordinate, yourYcoordinate)) < yourdistance
> ```